# Scale SVG element to given area using Snap animations

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

I would like to scale animate an SVG element to fit (preserving aspect ratio) a given area of the SVG.

I know about animate which performs relative animations

var s = Snap("#myelement");
   s.animate({ 'transform' : 't100,100s5,5,165,175' },1000);

In principle it should be possible to achieve what I want by computing the parameters of the translation and the scaling.
The problem there is that I do not find accurate documentation of the parameters.
The arguments of `t` seem to be the relative x,y position and that of `s` the scale factors and the coordinates of the scale center.
However, how does the combined translation and scaling work? Does the relative translation position scale with the scaling, etc.?

In other words: How do I compute the relative translation and scaling parameters from the coordinates of the upper left and the lower right corner of the animation target element?

Alternatively: Is there a more suitable animate function in Snap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Snap` uses SVG syntax, to solve the problem one needs to understand SVG transformations (see here for an introduction: https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/svg-transformations/). In order to set up a combined SVG transformation it is important to understand that each transformation changes the coordinate system (rather than just the properties of an element in an absolute coordinate frame).

If you combine two transformations, scaling and translation, this means that the parameters of the second transformation depends on the first one.

To achieve a translation and scaling of an element to a given location and size in the coordinates of the `ViewBox` of an SVG, one can first perform the scaling to the new size choosing the center coordinates for the scaling as the center of the element. Then considerations for the following translations simplify as follows

```
function startAnimation() {

var svg = Snap("#baseSVG");
/* get the bounding box of the svg */
var bboxSvg = svg.getBBox();

var s = Snap("#element");
/* get the bounding box of the element */
var bbox = s.getBBox();
/* get the required scale factor (assuming that we want to fit the element inside the svg bounding box) */
var scale = Math.min(bboxSvg.width/bbox.width,bboxSvg.height/bbox.height)*0.8;
/* compute the translation needed to bring center of element to center of svg 
the scale factor must be taken into account since the translation is based on the coordinate system obtained after the previous scaling */
var tx = (200-bbox.cx)/scale;
var ty = (200-bbox.cy)/scale;
/* perform the animation (make center of scaling the center of element) */
s.animate({ 'transform' : 's' + scale + ',' + scale + ',' + bbox.cx + ',' + bbox.cy + 't' + tx + ',' + ty },1000,mina.bounce);
s.drag();
}
```

This assumes that your SVG object has id `baseSVG` and the element you want to transform has id `element`. It is transformed such that it fits the SVG (adjust the factor 0.8 if you want it larger or smaller). If you know only the coordinates of the corners of the element you must first compute the center coordinates of the target (replace `bbox.cx` and `bbox.cy`) and the scale to apply this code snippet. This works in the obvious way in the coordinate frame of `baseSVG`.

Answer (score 0):

You show a transform with several parts. The order of these parts is important. If you translate first and scale later, the resulting translation is scaled too. If you scale first and then translate the resulting translation is not affected by the scaling.

The animation you use in Snap.svg is the one I also use. (However I consider migrating to [svg.js](http://svgjs.com/), since Snap.svg does not play well with [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/) for example. I have to do some testing first, though)